# помогите получить правильно css код для этого фона

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Прошу подсказать или исправить как правильно сделать фон с картинки и самое важное сделать его адаптивным
я в своём коде использую      clip-path: polygon(6% 0, 94% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 94% 100%, 6% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);

Но мне нужно чтоб было адаптивным
длина 850 px
ширина 50px

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: мне нужно как-то решить этот вопрос 
подскажите  пожалуйста

Comment: Что вам нужно  цвет узнать, или округленность сделать?

Comment: округленность сделать и что был адаптивен на странице

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет свойство `calc()`. Пример:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #7d1111;
  clip-path: polygon(0 10px, 10px 0, calc(100% - 10px) 0, 100% 10px, 100% calc(100% - 10px), calc(100% - 10px) 100%, 10px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 10px));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: круто! лайк однозначно )

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам пример, а для определения цвета используйте плагин Eye Dropper

```
.example {
  background: #7d1510;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: неее 
мне именно как на фото нужно 
с срезанными углами

Comment: Вместо процентов используйте пиксели. Открываете инспектор и экспериментируйте